# How to get more than one property and push json object into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this programs array of object which returns me the category id and the category name:

```
{
  categoryId: 101
  categoryName: "category name 1"
},
{
  categoryId: 102
  categoryName: "category name 2"
}
```

Using the below logic I was only storing category name into my categories array, but now I also only want to store category id into my array as a JSON object.

```
let categories = [];
_.map(programs, prog => {
  if(prog.subapplicationFlag === true && !categories.includes(prog.categoryName)) {
    return categories.push(prog.categoryName)
  }
})
```

can someone please help me with the solution to have the following array instead?

desired output:

**categories** array:

```
[
  {
    categoryId: 101
    categoryName: "category name 1"
  },
  {
    categoryId: 102
    categoryName: "category name 2"
  },
  {
    ... and so on
  },
]
```

Comment: As far as I can tell your input (the first code block) is the same as your desired output. Am I missing something?

Comment: @chazsolo - right now, my logic only returns the following in my categories array `["category name 1"]`. How can I build a json like object using both the category name and the id and then store it in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your block of code is pushing `prog.categoryName` into the categories array.

```
let categories = [];
_.map(programs, prog => {
  if(prog.subapplicationFlag === true && !categories.includes(prog.categoryName)) {
    return categories.push(prog.categoryName)
  }
})
```

Edit:

To return *both* the categoryName and categoryId, you can do `return categories.push({categoryName: prog.categoryName, categoryId: prog.categoryId})`

This will push an object into your category array.

Comment: Sorry james, I have modified my post above. right now, my logic only returns the following in my categories array ["category name 1"]. How can I build a json like object using both the category name and the id and then store it in the array?

Comment: @user10248088, Oh I see what you mean. Check out my revised answer above.

Comment: perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Glad to have helped! :)